# Why isn't Oauth setting email in tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth

```rb
# spec/support/omniauth_helper.rb

module OmniauthMacros
  def mock_auth_hash
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:github] = {
      'provider' => 'github',
      'uid' => '11',
      'info' => {
        'email' => 'gituser@github',
        'name' => 'gituser',
        'image' => 'mock_user_thumbnail_url'
      },
      'credentials' => {
        'token' => 'mock_token',
        'secret' => 'mock_secret'
      }
    }
  end
end
```

This returns
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email can't be blank`.
If I move this into Test environment config it starts working.  Why is this happening?

Comment: How are we supposed to know without seeing the test nor the object under test? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Agree, this is not enough information. My guess is that you failed to require the contents of the support directory in your spec_helper or rails_helper file. As an aside, have you considered using a shared context for this instead? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context